# Codeigniter MongoDB wrapper not working with delete

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am developing an API using Codeigniter and MongoDB (Alex Bilbie wrapper) and I cannot get the delete function to work properly.

It delete other documents than the one that I specify! It is driving me mad.

**This is the code in my model:**

```
$where = array (

  '_id' => new MongoId ($args['id'])

);

$result = $this -> mongo_db -> delete ('files', $where);
```

What is wrong? Is there something wrong with my code or the wrapper?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
$result = $this->mongo_db->where($where)->delete('files');
```

Not sure where you're getting your syntax--delete doesn't have a function defined with two parameters like that (at least in the version of the codeigniter wrapper I've been using).

Comment: What wrapper are you using? In Alex´s the code example is lacking.

Comment: I'm using Alex's wrapper, too. You have to look at the code: https://bitbucket.org/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongo-library/src/23948e56c40c/libraries/Mongo_db.php Search for `delete`, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Ah ok. Well that is not the most up to date repo. Use this: https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library

Comment: Interesting, I guess the bitbucket one is a few months behind. Well, if you look for the delete function there, there's still only one parameter. You're supposed to do it with `where` as I show in my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$where = array (

  '_id' => new MongoId ($args['id'])

);

$result = $this -> mongo_db -> where($where) -> delete_all('files');
```

Note that if you need to delete based on embedded document information

```
$result = $this -> mongo_db -> where(array('field.value'=>'x') -> delete_all('files');
```